# How to experimentally identify the exposed face of a crystal?

Tags: symmetry, crystals, experimental-technique

After depositing a material (e.g, TiO2) on a substrate, what methods can I use to check whether the material is crystalline, and what face (e.g, 001, 101, etc..) of the crystal is exposed?

Comment: x-ray diffraction mapping, electron backscatter diffraction, TEM, possibly light scattering if the material is not centro-symmetric, neutron scattering, ...

Answer (score 0):

You can use diffraction of low energy electrons (to study the crystalline surface) or X-ray crystallography (you can get the surface orientation from that also).